# Why this navbar menu using @Html.ActionLink in a .NET application is not working as I am expecting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I am not so into **.NET** and I have the following problem. Into a page I have a BootStrap navbar menu like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">

    @Html.ActionLink("Vidly_v2", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Movies", "Index", "Movies", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" type="text">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have the following problem with these 3 links:

```
<li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Movies", "Index", "Movies", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
```

because clicking on all these links the user is redirected to the following URLs (in the same order of the previous 



 tag:

```
http://localhost:60048/Movies?Length=4
```

and

```
http://localhost:60048/Movies?Length=9
```

and

```
http://localhost:60048/Movies?Length=6
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the helper method incorrectly!.

You are currently using the below overload of `ActionLink` helper.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink (this HtmlHelper helper, 
                                             string linkText, 
                                             string actionName, 
                                             string controllerName, 
                                             object routeValues);
```

The last parameter is for passing the route values which will be used to build the querystring. Currently you are passing the anonymous object for the html attributes to that.

Use this overload

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink (this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                                             string linkText, 
                                             string actionName, 
                                             string controllerName,
                                             object routeValues,
                                             object htmlAttributes);
```

If you do not have any route values to pass, simply pass `null` for the 4 the param (route values)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Movies", "Index", "Movies", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [`ActionLink` helper overload list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Object__), you're using 4 overloads:

```
public static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString ActionLink (this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
              string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes);
```

In this case, the controller name is treated as `routeValues` parameter, which becomes the reason why `Length` parameter value varies on each `href` link (`"Home".Length` = 4, `"Customers".Length` = 9 & `"Movies".Length` = 6).

You should use `ActionLink` helper with 5 overloads:

```
public static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString ActionLink (this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
              string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, 
              object htmlAttributes);
```

by passing `null` value to `routeValues` parameter like this:

```
<li class="nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Movies", "Index", "Movies", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
```